# Python AsyncGenerator typing

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, python-asyncio, python-typing, pylance

Below are two functions with different typing. Code runs as expected. PyCharm and mypy shows no warnings or errors also.

But VS Code shows alert on gen1() function:

> Return type of async generator function must be "AsyncGenerator" or
> "AsyncIterable" Pylance (reportGeneralTypeIssues)

So the questions are:

1. is "Optional" typing redundant in gen1() definition? (*I believe it is as there is no way to receive anything except AsyncGenerator as return value*)
2. is there problem in Pylance in VS Code with async typing ?

Code discussed:

```
import asyncio
from typing import AsyncGenerator, Optional

async def gen1() -> Optional[AsyncGenerator[str, None]]:
    while True:
        return
    yield "t"

async def gen2() -> AsyncGenerator[str, None]:
    while True:
        return
    yield "t"

async def main():
    print(f"{type(gen1())=}")
    print(f"{type(gen2())=}")
    async for d in gen1():
        print(d)
    
asyncio.run(main())
```

BTW, typing like in gen1 is used in some popular packages. Pyrogram example:
https://github.com/pyrogram/pyrogram/blob/master/pyrogram/methods/chats/get_chat_members.py

```
async def get_chat_members(
        self: "pyrogram.Client",
        chat_id: Union[int, str],
        query: str = "",
        limit: int = 0,
        filter: "enums.ChatMembersFilter" = enums.ChatMembersFilter.SEARCH
    ) -> Optional[AsyncGenerator["types.ChatMember", None]]:
```

Comment: `gen1` does not optionally return an async generator. It always returns an async generator, but sometimes it does not generate any items.

Comment: I would say mypy is correct because annotating something as `Optional[X]` when it clearly returns `X` is correct. On the other hand, there is no way for the function to be optionally async or optionally a generator, so VSCode is also correct to warn you about it. I don't feel like checking, but this may well be a configurable option in mypy.

Comment: @zvo Yes, using `--srict` option in mypy also generates eror message for gen1() call

Comment: The annotation of `gen1` is not _technically_ wrong, it simply too broad and thus misleading because `None` will **never** be returned by `gen1`, it will **always** return an asynchronous generator. It is analogous to writing `def f() -> Union[str, int]: return "a"`. Not wrong since `str` is a subtype `Union[str, int]`, but still makes no sense. As a general rule, return types should be as _narrow_ as possible (while parameter types should be as _broad_ as possible).

Comment: `Optional[AsyncGenerator[str, None]]` looks like auto-generated type annotations. A naive implementation of a return type inference may look for `return` statements, and infer `Optional[...]` for a lack of `return` in the function or a plain `return` without any value to return.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can safely remove `Optional`  from that code:

What does return an AsyncGenerator in this case is not any code you write: from the point the function is defined as `async` and have a `yield` in its body, the Python language itself will make it an `Async Generator Function` which sole possible return type, hardcoded in the language, is an AsyncGenerator - regardless of how the code is organized, or what will actually be executed when the code in the `def` block is actually run.

It indicates that the function is suitable to be used in an `async for` statement - or manually driven with `anext` and/or `send`, `throw`. Python itself will never return `None` when the function is called: instead the shortcircuit to the empty `return` only indicates the generator itself will be empty when iterated. As far as I know, there is no existing typing markup to indicate that a generator will be empty.

That would also be irrelevant as far as annotations are concerned, but for the fact that a Generator that would be marked as "will always be empty" could safely be thrown away without one trying to iterate over it: checking this kind of logic is beyond what static type annotation have to do (although some checkers are nice and do that - this is in the same category of "unused variable").